# Finding the Highest Frequencies in multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table, sapply

I have a data_frame containing 10 columns and 2000 rows. My sample data would  look like:

```
rs_id   Code    Combination_Ag  A.Ag    Combination_Bg  B.Ag    Combination_Cg  C.Ag
rs_1    0   1:01/1:01   1   13:02/13:02 1   03:04/03:04 6   1:01/1:01   1
rs_1    0   1:01/11:01  2   13:02/49:01 2   03:04/15:02 1   1:01/15:01  1
rs_1    1   1:01/2:01   6   13:02/57:01 1   03:04/7:01  2   1:01/3:01   1
rs_1    2   1:01/2:05:  1   13:02/8:01  1   06:02/06:02 3   1:01/4:04   1
rs_1    2   1:01/24:02  3   14:01/14:02 1   06:02/15:02 1   1:01/4:04   3
rs_2    0   1:01/3:01   1   14:01/7:02  1   06:02/2:02: 1   1:01/4:07   1
rs_2    1   1:01/31:01  1   15:01/15:01 1   06:02/3:03  1   1:01/7:01   2
rs_2    1   11:01/2:01  4   15:01/18:01 1   06:02/3:04  1   10:01/14:01 1
rs_2    2   11:01/25:01 1   15:01/44:02 2   06:02/4:01  1   10:01/3:01  5
```

I am trying to find the highest combination (A.Ag, B.Bg C.Ag) for rs_id =0, 1 and 2. How can I achieve this? 
The output would be

```
rs_1    0   1:01/11:01   2   13:02/49:01    2   03:04/03:04 6   1:01/1:01   1
rs_1    1   1:01/2:01    6   13:02/57:01    1   03:04/7:01  2   1:01/3:01   1
rs_1    2   1:01/24:02   3   06:02/06:02    3   06:02/15:02 1   1:01/4:04   3
rs_2    0   1:01/3:01    1   14:01/7:02     1   06:02/2:02: 1   1:01/4:07   1
rs_2    1   11:01/2:01   4   15:01/18:01    1   06:02/3:04  1   10:01/14:01 1 
rs_2    2   11:01/25:01  1   15:01/44:02    2   06:02/4:01  1   10:01/3:01  5
```

Comment: The "Combination_*" columns do not appear to have a natural order so picking a highest one poses a problem. The desired result suggests you want the highest  *.Ag value and the associated Combination in the same row and rs_id.

Comment: @42-I am sorry. I need to identify based on *.Ag counts only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach reshapes the data from wide to long format (melting *two* measure columns simultaneously), picks the row with the top `Ag` value for each unique combination of `rs_id`, `Code`, and `variable`. Finally, the result is reshaped from long to wide format again with the column order rearranged to return the expected result:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("Combination", "Ag")
melt(setDT(DF), measure.vars = patterns("Combination", "[A-D][.]Ag"), 
     value.name = cols)[
       , variable := forcats::lvls_revalue(variable, LETTERS[1:4])][
         , .SD[which.max(Ag)], by = .(rs_id, Code, variable)][
           , dcast(.SD, rs_id + Code ~ variable, value.var = cols)][
             , setcolorder(.SD, c(1:2, as.vector(outer(c(0, 4), 3:6, "+"))))]
```

> ```
>    rs_id Code Combination_A Ag_A Combination_B Ag_B Combination_C Ag_C Combination_D Ag_D
> 1:  rs_1    0    1:01/11:01    2   13:02/49:01    2   03:04/03:04    6     1:01/1:01    1
> 2:  rs_1    1     1:01/2:01    6   13:02/57:01    1    03:04/7:01    2     1:01/3:01    1
> 3:  rs_1    2    1:01/24:02    3    13:02/8:01    1   06:02/06:02    3     1:01/4:04    3
> 4:  rs_2    0     1:01/3:01    1    14:01/7:02    1   06:02/2:02:    1     1:01/4:07    1
> 5:  rs_2    1    11:01/2:01    4   15:01/15:01    1    06:02/3:03    1     1:01/7:01    2
> 6:  rs_2    2   11:01/25:01    1   15:01/44:02    2    06:02/4:01    1    10:01/3:01    5
> ```

#### Edit

The OP has asked for an explanation of the last of the chained `data.table` expressions `setcolorder(.SD, c(1:2, as.vector(outer(c(0, 4), 3:6, "+"))))`.

This expressions orders the columns of the result *by reference*, i.e., without copying. When reshaping multiple `value.var`s the columns are grouped by `value.var`:

```
melt(setDT(DF), measure.vars = patterns("Combination", "[A-D][.]Ag"), 
     value.name = cols)[
       , variable := forcats::lvls_revalue(variable, LETTERS[1:4])][
         , .SD[which.max(Ag)], by = .(rs_id, Code, variable)][
           , dcast(.SD, rs_id + Code ~ variable, value.var = cols)]
```

> ```
>    rs_id Code Combination_A Combination_B Combination_C Combination_D Ag_A Ag_B Ag_C Ag_D
> 1:  rs_1    0    1:01/11:01   13:02/49:01   03:04/03:04     1:01/1:01    2    2    6    1
> 2:  rs_1    1     1:01/2:01   13:02/57:01    03:04/7:01     1:01/3:01    6    1    2    1
> 3:  rs_1    2    1:01/24:02    13:02/8:01   06:02/06:02     1:01/4:04    3    1    3    3
> 4:  rs_2    0     1:01/3:01    14:01/7:02   06:02/2:02:     1:01/4:07    1    1    1    1
> 5:  rs_2    1    11:01/2:01   15:01/15:01    06:02/3:03     1:01/7:01    4    1    1    2
> 6:  rs_2    2   11:01/25:01   15:01/44:02    06:02/4:01    10:01/3:01    1    2    1    5
> ```

while the OP expects the output to be grouped by `variable`. So the desired column order is

`c(1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 8, 5, 9, 6, 10)`.

`1` and `2` denote the `id.var` columns. `as.vector(outer(c(0, 4), 3:6, "+")))` is just a way to save typing `3, 7, 4, 8, 5, 9, 6, 10`.

```
outer(c(0, 4), 3:6, "+")
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
> [1,]    3    4    5    6
> [2,]    7    8    9   10
> ```

```
as.vector(outer(c(0, 4), 3:6, "+"))
```

> ```
> [1]  3  7  4  8  5  9  6 10
> ```

#### Edit 2

The code can be further streamlined. The call to `as.vector()` is not necessary inside `c()` as  `c()` turns arrays into vectors. So, instead of

```
c(1:2, as.vector(outer(c(0, 4), 3:6, "+")))
```

we can write

```
c(1:2, outer(c(0, 4), 3:6, "+"))
```

#### Data

Note that I have completed the missing column headers for the last two columns.

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread(
  "rs_id   Code    Combination_Ag  A.Ag    Combination_Bg  B.Ag    Combination_Cg  C.Ag   Combination_Dg  D.Ag
rs_1    0   1:01/1:01   1   13:02/13:02 1   03:04/03:04 6   1:01/1:01   1
rs_1    0   1:01/11:01  2   13:02/49:01 2   03:04/15:02 1   1:01/15:01  1
rs_1    1   1:01/2:01   6   13:02/57:01 1   03:04/7:01  2   1:01/3:01   1
rs_1    2   1:01/2:05:  1   13:02/8:01  1   06:02/06:02 3   1:01/4:04   1
rs_1    2   1:01/24:02  3   14:01/14:02 1   06:02/15:02 1   1:01/4:04   3
rs_2    0   1:01/3:01   1   14:01/7:02  1   06:02/2:02: 1   1:01/4:07   1
rs_2    1   1:01/31:01  1   15:01/15:01 1   06:02/3:03  1   1:01/7:01   2
rs_2    1   11:01/2:01  4   15:01/18:01 1   06:02/3:04  1   10:01/14:01 1
rs_2    2   11:01/25:01 1   15:01/44:02 2   06:02/4:01  1   10:01/3:01  5"
)
```

Comment: was about to post something very similar :-)

Comment: Instead of using the `lvls_revalue`-function, you could also just use `variable := LETTERS[1:4][variable]` (which was the only difference between your approach and mine ;-) )

Comment: @jaap Good improvement, indeed. I am so used to use the `forcats` package when dealing with factors that it happens I forget the simple base R way.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. setcolorder(.SD, c(1:2, as.vector(outer(c(0, 4), 3:6, "+"))))]. could you explain this line pls?

Comment: @MSM I have added an explanation as requested.

Comment: @Uwe. Thank you so much for the explanation.